# Charring veg without gas burners/grill

Tags: vegetables

Without having a gas burner or a grill, is there still a way I can char vegetables such as a red pepper or corn on the cob? I have a glass-ceramic range and an oven - would I have to do it under the broiler?

Answer (score 3):

Coat the vegetables with a bit of oil and then place them in a hot oven. Your broiler should also work.

Comment: The broiler is probably a good way to go for peppers; turn them a few times and you can easily get most of the skin charred and the flesh cooked nicely. For corn, unless you want it cooked very little inside, you'll probably want to roast at a high temperature for a while rather than broiling.

Comment: I frequently get a nice char on loose corn kernels on the stove top starting with raw or frozen kernels and a bit of olive oil. Add some green onions or garlic at the end.

Answer (score 3):

As well as andleer's suggestion, you can also do it on a hot griddle pan, preferably cast iron.